# ¿Cómo cargar una imagen con canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo cómo cargar una imagen en canvas. 
Lo que hice:

```
var vp = document.getElementById("villaplatzi");
var papel = vp.getContext("2d");
var mapa = "tile.png";

var imagen = new Image();
imagen.src = mapa;
imagen.addEventListener("load", dibujar);

function dibujar()
{
  papel.drawImage(papel, 0, 0);
}

function aleatorio(min, maxi)
{
  var resultado;
  resultado = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxi - min + 1)) + min;
  return resultado;
}
```

Y me sale este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
>           at HTMLImageElement.dibujar

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No deberias usar `papel.drawImage(papel, 0, 0);` debes cambiarlo por

```
papel.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
```

Suponinedo que `imagen` este encontrando el archivo correcto para cargarlo en el canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un Ejemplo muy interesante y puedes sacar las coclusiones que quieras

```js
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
</script>
```